# FutureTask and HttpSession sync

Tags: java, multithreading, http, session

I have a long process (~10sec) which is triggered upon user request in my controller (spring 3.1 btw)

I was thinking to start a FutureTask in the controller and that an ajax request will query the server every sec to check for completion.

So, my questions are:

1. Has anyone done something like this? (somehow synchronize session value with a return value from FutureTask)? if so- I'd love the insight.
2. Do you have some cool idea on how to achieve this functionality (a http request in the controller which checks the state of a future task)?

Answer (score 0):

The new old hotness for this type of requirement is "[Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)" aka Ajax Push, Long-Polling, etc etc.  Basically instead of having clients hammer on your server asking "are you done yet?  are you done yet?  are you done yet?" you simply keep the socket open in an on-hold queue in the server and send them the data when it's done.

I don't know of any implementation that integrates directly with Spring, but there is a library called Atmosphere that works splendidly along side Spring.  It also has a jQuery plugin to save you from reinventing the wheel on the client side.  Rather than make my own feeble attempt at evangelism, I will simply leave you with the [creator's blog](http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/).

Comment: I know comet for a long time. Atmosphere is pretty cool, but I'm actually looking for a solution that doesn't include servlet 3.0.